# Why does setThumbImage no longer work with UISlider (Xcode 9)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode9

`setThumbImage` has not been deprecated. This used to work just fine:

```
[scrubBar setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"scrub-arrow.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Is the image still valid? Try to display it in a regular `UIImageView` to verify.

Comment: What are you trying to do, what did you try, and **what results did you get**?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. My usage of [UISlider appearance] elsewhere in the code overrode setThumbImage. My bad.